# Watch command for Node.js HTTP Server

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express and every time I make a change to my controller, I need to restart the HTTP server, which is somewhat inconvenient. Is there a "watch" command or an equivalent in express or Node.js that watches for changes and restarts the server automatically?

Comment: Are you sure you want to restart the whole server just because a single file changed? You might want to work that into the architecture of your server to `watch()` but it's very costly to just restart the whole thing.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum javascript and node.js do not have a reliable hot code reloading mechanism, at least not one that is mainstream at the moment. Most folks make due with a full process restart, which is usually done by the time you switch from your editor to your browser and hit reload.

Comment: lets say i make a spelling error, right now iam killing server in command line restarting then going to the browser which is a drag for just a spelling error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To watch files for changes, you could use `fs.watch()` or `fs.watchFile()`. However, daemon modules such as [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) or [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) exist for your purpose.

Answer (score 24):

Try [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), it will restart your application every time you made a change

Comment: Yes, I was able to configure it for WebStorm.

Answer (score 8):

I use [node-dev](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev) for automatic restart on source code change.

Comment: ..not sure how node-dev would do this correctly...is this working for you still? seems sketchy

Comment: Still works fine for me. It's job is pretty straightforward. If you are seeing issues maybe report them to the project's github repo.

Comment: awesome! this one is easier plus the desktop notification about the file changes locations.

Comment: Really easy to set up. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Since Node v18.11.0 there is a built-in "watch" argument that re-runs the script on change to it, and it's sub-files.

```bash
node --watch index.js
```